# xerces hell when redeploying

Tags: spring, weblogic, xerces

Dears,

when I redeploy our application and try to log in I get this nice cozy stacktrace:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: #{AuthenticationBean.authenticate}: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at be.fgov.just.cjr.application.authentication.openam.OpenAmRedirectFilter.doFilter(OpenAmRedirectFilter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.resolver.readers.SAXCatalogReader.readCatalog(SAXCatalogReader.java:238)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.resolver.Catalog.parseCatalog(Catalog.java:683)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.xml.XmlUtil.createDefaultCatalogResolver(XmlUtil.java:288)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:234)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:197)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:145)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:93)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:680)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.LocalJaxWsServiceFactory.createJaxWsService(LocalJaxWsServiceFactory.java:125)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.prepare(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.invoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:484)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy581.listSystemParameters(Unknown Source)
    at be.fgov.just.cjr.application.authentication.ExtractAuthenticationBean.doAuthenticate(ExtractAuthenticationBean.java:80)
    at be.fgov.just.cjr.application.authentication.ExtractAuthenticationBean.authenticate(ExtractAuthenticationBean.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:329)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:342)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.invoke(AstPropertySuffix.java:58)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
    at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 34 more
```

Which kind of strikes me as strange because it happens when you:

1. Start the server and deploy (and log in; use the application;...).
2. Redeploy.
3. Try to authenticate (for the second time since server start).

One might think that when you deploy and log in and use the application and after that redeploy the application and log in again the exact same xerces libs should remain loaded in the VM so this ClassCastException shouldn't occur at all...

What am I missing here?

Already thanks for enlightening me ;)

A workaround for this issue is restarting the server but a structurally better solution would certainly be appreciated...

S.

edit:
(sorry for the late reply)

this is my weblogic.xml (for the module that suffers from the issue)

-> the suffering application is a war

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
        xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.1/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <wls:weblogic-version>10.3.5</wls:weblogic-version>

    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>antlr.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.faces.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.ajax4jsf.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.httpclient.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.vfs.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.lang.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.beanutils.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.apache.xmlcommons.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.apache.xerces.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:context-root>cjcs-cg</wls:context-root><!-- can be overwritten by a plan.xml -->

</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Comment: Looks like you have 2 versions of xerces jars: possibly one in the server libraries and one in your app. Look into how weblogic does the class loading and if you can do something about it... Alternatively, you could try excluding xerces.jar from your war file...

Comment: What does your weblogic.xml file have in it? Are you deploying a war or ear file?